# SSRS subscription for parent and child report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to combine a subscription for two reports into one? More specifically, a parent and child report.

I need to email out a report that has a sub report and wanted to see if this was possible. I have looked online and couldn't see anything so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may be looking for [shared schedules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/new-shared-schedule-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You can also build a report that only contains the parent and child report and send that